# Can anyone explain what a superleak is?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, superfluidity

In the context of Helium can anyone explain what a [superleak](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superleak) is and why it could be useful?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57481/

Answer (score 5):

A superleak is the same as an ordinary leak (namely a hole in a container) but it has a microscopic size. Therefore no regular fluid can escape the container through this hole because its viscosity is too high. A regular fluid will rather just sit over the hole.

However, In liquid Helium-II, below the transition temperature (also called the $\lambda$ point, $T_{\lambda} \sim 2.17\,\mathrm{K}$), the superfluid phase has zero viscosity. This means it *can* migrate through the hole, rather easily even. A great demonstration with commentary can be found here: [Alfred Leitner - Liquid Helium II the Superfluid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eZlF6IToQs&t=15m57s) (between 15:57 and 18:00, but the rest of the clip is definitely worth a watch as well).

---

As for your question about how this can be useful, I can only think of two.

- A first use is quite simply testing for microscopic holes in a material.
- A second use is slightly more sophisticated. So-called Oscillating Superleak Transducers (OSTs) are sensors used to detect [Second Sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_sound) in liquid Helium-II (or any other superfluid we may find). Second sound is basically a temperature wave in Helium-II below the $\lambda$ point. This effect is also demonstrated and commented on in the clip I linked to earlier.

If you're looking for everyday uses, the temperatures at which this effect occurs are pretty damn low, so that's not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

As how it can be useful, to obtain ultra-cold neutrons, one can confine neutrons in a volume of superfluid Helium at around 1 K and cool them by collsions with Helium. However, you'll need to eliminate Helium 3 to avoid neutron capture. Since at this temperature, only Helium 4 is superfluid and can pass through superleak, therefore effectively eliminating Helium 3.